# KeyPress and keyup in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to allow only numbers and decimal in a inputtext field.
If I use my code in a keypress event it works fine(return false when alphabets are entered), but when i use it with keyup it is not.
My code:

```
function OnKeyPress(e,DivID) {

if ( e.which != 8 && e.which != 0  && e.which != 13 && e.which != 190 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
     return false;
                    //  event.preventDefault(); 
   }

   var val = j$('[id$='+DivID+']').val();


   if(DivID == 'ProximityCPPercentage')
   {
       var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
       if(val.indexOf('.') >= 0 && e.which == 46)
          return false;
       else if(e.which == 46 && val.length == 3)
          return false;
       if(val.indexOf('.') == 0)
          val = '0' + val;
       if(e.which != 46)
       {                        
           strval = val + String.fromCharCode(x);
           var re = /^((.|0|[1-9]\d?)(\.\d{1})?|100(\.0?)?)$/;
           if(!re.test(strval))
              return false;
        }
    }              
    else if(val.indexOf('.') >= 0)
    {

        var reg =/^(\d{0,4}\.?(\d{0,1})|\d{0,6})?$/gm;                   
        if(!reg.test(val)) 
        {
            j$('[id$='+DivID+']').val(val.substring(0, val.length - 1));                    
        }

    }                
    else if(e.which != 190 )
    {
        if(val.length > 5)                        
        return false;
    } 

}
```

If I use this function in onkeypress attribute of input field it is not allowing alphabets but when i use in onkeyup it does allows the alphabets.

Comment: The two different events have differences, some keycodes aren't neccessarely the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I created a simple fiddle with an explanation of what is happening for you https://jsfiddle.net/gb0kwom0/3/

On key down, will capture the event before a value is set in the input (result: alert fire then nothing in input value), see this example.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return onPress()">

<script>
    function onPress(){alert(); return false;}
</script>
```

On key up, will capture the event after a value is set in the input (result: value set then alert will fire), see this example.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="return onUp()">

<script>
    function onUp(){alert(); return false;}
</script>
```

So to solve your issue onKeyUp you will need to reset the value.

The result will be: will capture the event after a value is set in the input then reset the value back to empty, see this example.

**note: this example is just to show the difference and should not be used, it will reset the whole value back to nothing**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="onUp2(this)">

<script>
    function onUp2(obj){alert();  obj.value='';}
</script>
```

**this method is not ideal and will take a lot more code to get working, it is why you should continue to use onkeypress instead**